# Question on abstract algebra about invertiblity?

Tags: abstract-algebra, examples-counterexamples

Let $(G,*)$ be a group.

Could anyone give me an example $a,b\in G$ such that
$$a*b=e\mbox{ and } b*a\neq e $$
Where $e$ is the identity element.

I would appreciate any help.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: @StudentofEuler2718 Such groups would be non-abelian, but they wouldn't satisfy the property in question.

Comment: It's confusing to use $\land$ in basically any context except formal logic; here, for example, it looks like a second algebraic operation that you're trying to perform on $e$ and $b$ (e.g. a wedge / exterior product). Just write "and." It's okay, really.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't possible in a group. If $ab = e$, then $b=a^{-1}$ and $a=b^{-1}$, which implies $ba=e$.